# How to represent active low variables?

Tags: c, embedded, naming-conventions

I've found trailing '#' characters in the pin description section in some datasheets, which indicates that the specific pin has *active-low* functionality.

Is there any conventions for variable names which hold for example pulled up GPIO input pin values?

Comment: Why would you need such a thing as "active low variables"? You can always map to correct active level when doing the I/O operation and normally don't need to care about signal levels of your hardware.

Comment: So this is the preferred way, thank you!

Comment: This is method is suitable for small numbers of pins each handled separately. If you write a function by hand for each pin, then you can invert or not invert the logic separately according to the need for each pin. This allows you to give the function a name that is refers to the meaning not the voltage level. However, suppose you need to create an enum with a hundred entries for all the various pins, and all the entries of the enum gets passed to a single function for output.  In this case you still need to name the entries of the enum in a way that makes it clear that the line is active low.

Comment: The signal itself could be labelled like I̅N̅P̅U̅T̅ and if you want to mimic this it could be `bar_input`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I'd either read that as "input from the bar" or "the opposite of `foo_input`" :) I think `input_inv` would be the most common naming convention in C.

Comment: @Lundin perhaps, but I have yet to use the foo-bar paradigm, in either real or example code. I find them completely opaque: meaning their use blinds me to what they are supposed to be representing or illustrating. Avoid.

Comment: @WeatherVane I believe the etymology of foo and bar claims they come from FUBAR. And no, I'm not using either of those in real code either :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very helpful when translating a schematic to a header file with constants for the pin numbers to name the constants as close as possible to the net names on the schematic.

This leaves three problems that I have encountered regularly:

1. Net names with a dash: I just replace this with an underscore.  `BAT-LEVEL` becomes `BAT_LEVEL`.
2. Net names starting with a digit: I start all the pin numbers with the same prefix: `3V3_ENABLE` becomes `PIN_3V3_ENABLE`.
3. Net names with a slash or hash character or overbar (all of which signify active low).  I replace this with a lower-case `n` in an otherwise all-capitals constant.  `SPI_CS#` becomes `SPI_nCS`.

Answer (score 2):

The common signal naming conventions in datasheets and schematics would be either a `\` prefix or a line above the text. Neither can be used in C.

So the most common naming convention I've seen in C is probably a postfix `_inv` for inverted signals. Or perhaps less commonly using `inv_` as prefix.

You might in some cases want to add a bit of abstraction layer to variably switch a GPIO pin from active high to active low in software.